# Publishing Service not updating Content Delivery after publish

Tags: publishing, caching, publishing-service

I've installed the Publishing Service on my Sitecore 9.0 Update-2 environment with dedicated CM und CD server.

The publishing process seems to work. So when I publish an item on my CM I can look into the web database and the published content is there.

But on my CD I am not getting the changes directly only after restarting the Application.

I've added the following files to the bin on my CD and CM

- Sitecore.Framework.Conditions.dll
- Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Abstractions.dll
- Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Delivery.dll
- Sitecore.Publishing.Service.dll

and I've added this config to /Modules/PublishingService

- Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Delivery.config

same content on CD and CM:

```
    <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
        <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentDelivery or ContentManagement">
            <hooks>
                <hook type="Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Delivery.PublishTargetEventsHook, Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Delivery" />
            </hooks>

            <!--
        SITECORE EVENTS
        -->
            <events>
                <event name="publishingservice:searchindex:rebuild">
                    <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Delivery.TargetSearchIndexRebuildHandler, Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Delivery" method="RebuildTargetSearchIndex">
                        <IndexNames hint="list:AddIndex">
                            <index>sitecore_web_index</index>
                        </IndexNames>
                    </handler>
                </event>

                <event name="publishingservice:cache:clear">
                    <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Delivery.TargetDataCacheClearHandler, Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Delivery" method="ClearTargetDataCaches" />
                </event>
            </events>
        </sitecore>
    </configuration>
```

I don't know If I am missing some configuration.

Comment: Have you reviewed this post? https://mikael.com/2019/07/learnings-from-a-year-of-implementing-sitecore-publishing-service/ It seems to align with what you are seeing.

Comment: I've read the post but doesn't help me :-/

Comment: Which version of publishing service are you using ?

Comment: Version 3.1.3 i am using

Comment: Have you disabled the publishingservice:searchindex:rebuild event on the CD (assuming it is not responsible for indexing) as per the manual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I have some more sites then just the default website. So I need to add the following code snipped to my configs on the CD for example inside the Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Delivery.config

```
 <event name="publish:end:remote">
            <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache">
                <sites hint="list">
                    <site name="MySite1-AT">MySite1-AT</site>
                    <site name="MySite1-DE">MySite1-DE</site>
                </sites>
            </handler>
        </event>
```

and then also the cache was reseted on my CD

Comment: This would indicate that your cache clearing was not set up correctly before you installed the Publishing Service

Comment: @sitecorium what you mean with cache clearing setup? Never heared before.

Comment: I think @sitecorium means this issue existed regardless of using the Sitecore Publishing Service.

Comment: I had the same experience. It appears that the default Sitecore setup only adds "website" to the list. In a multi-site setup this was the key to configuring the separate sites for caching. Also enable the `cacheHtml="true"` in the main site config for each site.